# Check if dictionary key, value pairs meet user-defined search conditions

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of the form:

```
dict = {'a':25, 'ab':3.3, '(cd)': 4, 'ef':35, 'gh':12.2, etc.}
```

a user enters a comma separated phrase (search string) like:

```
'a > 5, 0 < (cd) < 6, ef < 35'
```

Above we have three conditions, but it could be any number of conditions: What I would like is to check if my dictionary satisfies ALL search conditions.

```
 if dict meets all conditions:
     do somthing
 else:
     do something else
```

I can take the search string, do split(','), loop over each condition, extract the key, the comparison operator (< or >), and the number, and check if my dict meets all conditions. In the example above dict['a'] > 5 is met, 0 < dict['(cd)'] < 6 is also met, but dict['ef'] < 35 is not met.

Is there a quicker and more elegant way to do this? A better and smarter way to go from 'a > 5' to dict['a'] > 5? For example, can I convert my dict to a Pandas dataframe, and do some checks? Is there an evaluation method, or something similar in Python aside from the brute force method that I am trying?

Comment: Evil suggestion: `locals().update(my_dict); conditions = [eval(condition) for condition in search_string.split(',')]`

Comment: oh, won't work because of `(cd)`.
Also has a million other downsides, was just for the "code golfing" challenge.

Comment: thanks. without knowing what 'a' is, eval('a>5') won't work

Comment: I upgraded my answer to 2.0. It splits on operators instead of space, but allows space. It can cast to bool, int, float, str or None and do all of the most basic comparisons between them.

Comment: @Murchak that's the `"locals().update()"` part, give it a try...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't very hard to build a parser for this. You can use the `operator` package to handle the conditions, and other than that, it's just a bunch of formatting and looping data.

```py
import operator, re

# dictionary of operators
operators = {'<' :operator.lt,
             '<=':operator.le,
             '==':operator.eq,
             '>=':operator.ge,
             '>' :operator.gt,
             '!=':operator.ne
             }
        
# format operators keys for regex group
_oper = '|'.join(operators.keys())
        
# regex
oper   = re.compile(fr'\s*({_oper})\s*').split
number = re.compile(r'-?\d*(\.\d+)?').fullmatch
string = re.compile(r'("|\')(?P<str>.*)\1').fullmatch

def cast(value:str) -> float|int|bool|str|None:
    out = None
    
    if (v := value.lower()) in ('true', 'false'):
        out = v == "true"
    elif m := string(value):
        out = m.group('str')
    elif m := number(value):
        out = (int,float)['.' in v](v)
        
    return out

def check_conditions(data:dict, conditions:str) -> bool:
    # stores condition results
    facts = []

    for cond in conditions.split(','):
        # stores values and operators
        v, o = [], []
        
        # parse values and operators
        for c in oper(cond):
            if (c := c.strip()) in operators:
                # store operator function
                o.append(operators.get(c))
            else:
                # try data[c] else cast c
                v.append(data.get(c, cast(c)))
              
        # make sure values length is one more than operators              
        if (len(v) - len(o)) != 1:
            raise ValueError
            
        # call all operator functions on values and store results
        facts += [o[i](*v[i:i+2]) for i in range(len(o))]
    
    return all(facts)
```

##### usage

```py
data  = {'a':25, 'ab':3.3, '(cd)': 4, 'ef':35, 'gh':.2, 'ij':"hello", 'kl':False, "mn":None}

conds = 'mn==None, a>5, 0<(cd)<5, 35==ef!=34>12<20, ij==\'hello\''  
print(check_conditions(data, conds)) #True
```

Comment: Thank you OysterShucker very much! I'll mark this as an answer. Other people could still feel free to post alternative solutions.

Comment: @Murchak - the whole power of it is due to python having a package where operators are functions. If it wasn't for that this would be a mess of conditional statements. Also, just adding to the `oper` dict will expand all the possibilities without you having to change anything else. For instance you could add `'!=':operator.ne`, and it will just work.

Answer (score 0):

As [Adam.Er8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5052365/adam-er8) pointed out in the comments, `eval` is an extremely quick and dirty way to do this (not exactly elegant, but it does the job). However, there are two parts to his code golf answer that don't make it work very well in practice:

1. It obviously doesn't work, as you need it to parse the identifiers into your dictionary notation, and
2. eval is notoriously unsafe - you should never pass in any input of which you can't be sure of the origin or format, as the user could inject malicious code through the input.

I'm going to solve both these problems with regex. First, we'll make the following assumptions about your problem:

1. A valid key in your dictionary consists of some number of symbols without any whitespace, commas, or comparators. It also can't just be all digits (because then there would be nothing distinguishing it from a number, and the problem would quickly become unsolvable). Do note that you may want to ban parentheses apart from the most outer ones to prevent things like func
2. A valid comparator is < or >, optionally with an '=' behind it

This means that an identifier has the regex `ident_re = r"([^><=,\s]*[^0-9><=,\s]+[^><=,\s]*)"`, and a valid expression (between commas) has the regex `^(([^><=,\s]+)(\s*([><]=?)\s*([^><=,\s]+))+)$` (further explanation of the regexes below).

Now, we can use some higher order functions to conduct your tests:

```py
import re


d = {'a':25, 'ab':3.3, '(cd)': 4, 'ef':35, 'gh':12.2}
s = 'a > 5, 0 < (cd) < 6, ef < 35'

s = list(map(lambda p: p.strip(), s.split(",")))
safety_re = r"^(([^><=,\s]+)(\s*([><]=?)\s*([^><=,\s]+))+)$"
ident_re = r"([^><=,\s]*[^0-9><=,\s]+[^><=,\s]*)"
if any(map(lambda p: not re.match(safety_re, p), s)):
    # if it reaches here, the eval expression is not safe or properly formatted
    unsafe = list(filter(lambda p: not re.match(safety_re, p), s))
    print(f"ERROR: unsafe input(s) - {unsafe}")
elif all(map(lambda p: eval(re.sub(ident_re, lambda m: str(d[m.group(1)]), p)), s)):
    # checks that all the conditions are met by evaluating each and making sure all are True
    print("DO SOMETHING")
else:
    # expression is fine but not all the conditions are met
    print("DO SOMETHING ELSE")
```

#### Regular Expression Explanation

As above, we've crafted the regexes `r"([^><=,\s]*[^0-9><=,\s]+[^><=,\s]*)"` for identifiers, and `^(([^><=,\s]+)(\s*([><]=?)\s*([^><=,\s]+))+)$` for comparison expressions.

For the identifier expression, the character set `[^><=,\s]*` represents any non-banned character (this is allowed to repeat 0 or more times) and the character set `[^0-9><=,\s]+` (allowed to repeat 1 or more times) represents a non-banned character that is not a digit. Therefore, the overall expression just looks for a single word (without spaces, as whitespace is not allowed by banning `\s`), such that at least one character is not a digit.

For the comparator expression, we have `[^><=,\s]+` for any identifier or number, and `([><]=?)` for a valid comparator. The comparator expression consists of an identifier or number, followed by 1 or more repetitions of (a comparator and then an identifier or number).

Comment: Thanks Yi! I will go through and decipher what is happening.